# Unable to call javascript function django rest API

Tags: javascript, python, html, api, django-rest-framework

Hi I am beginner in html and javascript.  I have written few REST API's using python django application. I am trying to call login API from html and Javascript. But not able to call function and my API URL.

Here is the code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'>
```

```
   $('#send').click(function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();

    data = {

        "username": $('#username').val(),

        "password": $('#password').val()

     };

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",

        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/",

        data: JSON.stringify(data),

        dataType: "json",

        contentType: "application/json",

        success: function(data) {console.log(data)},

        error: function (rs, e) {console.debug(rs)}

    });

});
```

```
            <div class="grad"></div>

            <div class="header">

                    <div>Site<span>Random</span></div>

            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="login">

                            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>

                            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>

                            <input type="submit" id="send" class="btn" href="#">Send</a>

            </div>
```

I am running my django application in the following way
Python manager.py runserver:8000 port. I am able to get the response via postman. But not able to get response when calling from index.html

Your help appreciated

Comment: are using a `document.ready` or `$(function(){})`. to wait for the  DOM to load.

Comment: How can i use it here.

Comment: do a console.log() in your click handler and see if the log shows. If it doesn't show that means jquery didn't find the elements because the page wasn't ready.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I am getting below error

Comment: Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Now i am able to call the function. While giving login request getting above error

Answer (score 0):

all your code should be inside a [`document.ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). not sure if you are using it but I don't see it in your code. I see that you are selecting elements ok.

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

> page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready()